# Относительный путь до файла на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу добавить относительный путь в консольную программу на Python. (для возможности портирования на другие ПК).
Пишет "No such file or directory". Абсолютный путь работает.
Пытался каким-то образом изменить активную директорию, но не смог.

```
def download_fiels():
    with open("../wordbooks/russian_nouns.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        WORD_LIST = [row.strip() for row in file]

    with open("../wordbooks/russian_pril.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        QUALITY_LIST = [row.strip() for row in file]

    with open("../wordbooks/russian_imena.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        NAME_LIST = [row.strip() for row in file]
    return WORD_LIST, QUALITY_LIST, NAME_LIST
```

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` для отладки. `os.chdir(path)` чтобы поменять текущий каталог. Я, правда, `chdir` не люблю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В питоне есть зарезервированная переменная `__file__`, в которую записывается путь до загруженного модуля. В данном случае её можно использовать таким образом:

```
import os

with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
          + "/wordbooks/russian_nouns.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # код
```

Так Вы сможете вызывать исполняемый файл вашей программы из любой директории.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш метод решил мою проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить абсолютный путь до каталога, где расположен скрипт и уже с его помощью добиваться работы с относительными путями.

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

Предлагаю в данном случае сохранить путь до каталога с ресурсами, у вас это "wordbooks", который лежит внутри каталога выше уровнем. Способ велосипедистый.

```
wordbooks_dir = basedir[:-(len(basedir.split('\\')[-1]) + 1)]
```

Здесь мы из базового пути убираем последний каталог через срез строки.
Собственно последующая работа с файлами должна быть такой:

```
open(f"{wordbooks_dir}/russian_nouns.txt", encoding='utf-8')
```

**Дополнение: Обнаружил некостыльный способ обратиться к родительскому каталогу.**

```py
workbooks_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basedir, '..'))
open(os.path.join(wordbooks_dir, '/russian_nouns.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Способ Сергея не помог. 
  File "C:\Matvey\Programm\Python\dop\pole_chud\pole_chudes_oop.py", line 223, in download_fiels
    with open(f"{wordbooks_dir}/russian_nouns.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\C/russian_nouns.txt'

Способ Станислава не решает изначальной проблемы (мы не знаем путь до файла пользователя другого ПК).

Comment: Способ рабочий, просто допустил ошибку со смещением при срезах. Исправлено

Comment: Увы, исправленный метод тоже не помог: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/russian_nouns.txt'. Спасибо за уделенное время. Решил проблему методом alex6712.

Answer (score 0):

У меня вышеописанные способы не сработали, нашел универсальней и адаптированней для создания dataframe сразу:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

directory_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

file_name = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_path, "file_name.csv"))
```

Comment: В вопросе нет ничего про Pandas и датафреймы )